# Failed trying to use the Windows dynamic library function AssocQueryStringA

Tags: flutter, dart, winapi, ffi

In a Flutter application, I'm trying to use the function `AssocQueryStringA`  to query some info about a file extension. By dart:ffi I'm using the following code to declare and load the function:

```
final _shlwapi = DynamicLibrary.open('shlwapi.dll');

static int assocQueryString(
      int flags,
      int str,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszAssoc,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszExtra,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszOut,
      Pointer<Uint32> pcchOut) =>
  _assocQueryString(flags, str, pszAssoc, pszExtra, pszOut, pcchOut);

static final _assocQueryString = _shlwapi.lookupFunction<
  Uint32 Function(
      IntPtr flags,
      IntPtr str,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszAssoc,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszExtra,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszOut,
      Pointer<Uint32> pcchOut),
  int Function(
      int flags,
      int str,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszAssoc,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszExtra,
      Pointer<Utf16> pszOut,
      Pointer<Uint32> pcchOut)>('AssocQueryStringA');
```

Then I call the function with this code, I passed `ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYAPPNAME` with the value of `4` in the second argument:

```
Pointer<Utf16> temp = wsalloc(MAX_PATH);
Pointer<Uint32> tempSize = malloc<DWORD>();
assocQueryString(0, 4, TEXT(".xlsx"), nullptr, temp, tempSize);
var tt = temp.toDartString();
```

but the value returned in the `tt`  variable is not readable as the following image show:

[image: value returned in tt]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling the "ANSI" version of the function (`AssocQueryStringA`) but are passing `Pointer<Utf16>`.  "ANSI" versions of Windows functions use strings with 1-byte code units encoded in the system's local encoding.  If you want to use UTF-16, you should be calling the "wide" version instead (`AssocQueryStringW`).

Comment: you are right, that was my mistake, thank you